# Error In Rendering Jade Files

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I get an error while rendering the Jade file. The code that I use in app.js is:

```
app.get('/photos/new' function(req, res) {
      res.render('/photos/new', {
        locals: {
          photo: new Photo()
        }
      });
    });
```

The corresponding Jade file is:

```
h1 New Photo
form(action='/photos', method ='post', enctype ='form-data')
  != partial('../partials/photo_form', { locals: { photo: photo}})
  p
    input(type = 'submit')
```

But I get an error saying photo is not defined. I don't know where I am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locals in the partial is implied, so give this a try:

```
!= partial('../partials/photo_form', {photo: photo})
```

Answer (score 1):

when doing partial include, it refers to the current directory the view is in..

so the response you are rendering comes from:

/views/photos/new.jade

right?
so then the partial include is in the new.jade file.. which means if you do

partial('../partials/photo_form',{'whatever':'whatever'})

its looking in:

/views/partials/photo_form.jade

is that what you are expecting?
because if it is in

/views/photos/photo_form.jade

just do partials('photo_form',{'whatever':'whatever'})

and it will default to the directory the parent view is in.
http://expressjs.com/guide.html

and check view lookup

cheers